# Parsing Json array inside Json array and extracting unique values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js

I am consuming an API thats returning  the JSON response like below.

```
[
  [
    "Tab",
    "Service 1",
    172
  ],
  [
    "Admin",
    "Service 2",
    159
  ],
  [
    "Admin",
    "Service 3",
    5
  ],
  [
    "Admin",
    "Service 4",
    5
  ],
  [
    "Alerts",
    "Service 2",
    159
  ],
  [
    "Summary",
    "Service 1",
    99
  ],
  [
    "Import",
    "Service 2",
    71
  ],
  [
    "Covered",
    "Service 2",
    63
  ],
  [
    "Settings",
    "Service 2",
    53
  ],
  [
    "Application Config",
    "Service 2",
    51
  ]
]
```

I need to get the unique services from this list in javascript. 
Expected Response:

```
["Service 1", "Service 2", "Service 3", "Service 4"]
```

How can i achieve this? I tried using underscorejs.org/#uniq, but not helping me. Can any one help?

Comment: `Array.from(new Set(input.map(row => row[1])))` where `input` is your data.

Comment: This worked. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use `map` on the return array to get just the values you're interested in, and then get the unique values in that.

```
let uniqueServices = _.uniq(apiResponse.map(r => r[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks @carebdayrvis, this helped very much